Align Header Logo to the left
Update: After playing around with the code a little, the top line of the CSS is causing the issue, specifically the margin:0; If I remove it, the logo moves to the left. Otherwise the logo begins at the end of the top menu. So, the whole time it looked like it was centered, it's actually just being pushed over by the top menu.
Original post: I have a logo in my header with a navigation bar above and below. The logo always is centered. How do I get this to align left. I have updated from the original post to add some code that was missing.
* { margin:0; padding: 0;  outline: 0; }
  body, html { height: 100%;}


footer,
header,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

.shell {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
}

#header {
  height: 82px;
  float: left;
}

#logo {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}

#navigation,
#topnav {
  height: 37px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #1B2A47;
}

#navigation ul,
#topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#navigation ul li,
#topnav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 2px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#navigation ul li a,
#topnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 22px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#topnav ul li a:hover {
  color: #7DC33A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li.first a,
#topnav ul li.first a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#navigation a.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="shell">
    <nav id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <header id="header">
        <h1 id="logo"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/80" alt="Logo" /></h1>
      </header>

      <nav id="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Menu<span class="arr"></span></a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
 </div>


It's not centered. It's floated, and snagging on a floated element above it. Try clearing the float

The snippet results do not seem to match your description of the problem. Please edit your description and/or the snippet so that it is clear to the community what the problem is.

Use the code below to set your logo to the left alignment, also add the closing div to the missing in your HTML code.


footer,
header,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}

.shell {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  background: #fff;
}

#header {
  height: 82px;
}

#logo {
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid silver;
}

#navigation,
#topnav {
  height: 37px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #1B2A47;
}

#navigation ul,
#topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#navigation ul li,
#topnav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 2px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#navigation ul li a,
#topnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 22px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#topnav ul li a:hover {
  color: #7DC33A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li.first a,
#topnav ul li.first a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#navigation a.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="shell">
        <nav id="topnav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">
            <header id="header">
                <h1 id="logo"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/80" alt="Logo" /></h1>
            </header>

            <nav id="navigation">
                <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Menu<span class="arr"></span></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



Your logo should be set as the left side when using the above code, also if you want to set your logo in the center just update the CSS only to center your logo.
#logo { text-align: center; }


Thanks for your response. I added some more information to the question. The top line * { margin: 0; padding: 0; outline: 0; } is causing the issue. When I remove margin: 0; the logo goes to the left.  @Prashant

@cjenkins08 I get your point. in your CSS you apply float:left property to navigation li tag Sometimes float affects to their sibling also. If you need to not apply the float property to sibling element just add CSS to #header {clear: both;}

This fixed it. Thanks! @Prashant



#header {
  height: 82px;
  float: left;
  width: 100%; /* make header span width */
}

#logo {
  height: 80px;
  align: left; /* align logo to left */
}

#navigation,
#topnav {
  height: 37px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #1B2A47;
  clear: both; /* ensure nav bars dont overlap the logo */
}

#navigation ul,
#topnav ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

#navigation ul li,
#topnav ul li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 2px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#navigation ul li a,
#topnav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 22px 0 22px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li a:hover,
#topnav ul li a:hover {
  color: #7DC33A;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li.first a,
#topnav ul li.first a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

#navigation a.nav-btn {
  display: none;
}
<nav id="topnav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<header id="header">
  <h1 id="logo"> <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" /></h1>
</header>

<nav id="navigation">
  <a href="#" class="nav-btn">Menu<span class="arr"></span></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="link.html">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>




For some reason that didn't work on my end. These are the two divs above the top nav
 <div class="shell">
<nav id="topnav">```
And I did miss this in the code directly above the header:
```<div class="container">  // this gets closed toward bottom of page  
<header id="header">
  <h1 id="logo"> <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" /></h1>
</header>```

The only CSS I have for the wrapper/shell/ container is this:
```.shell {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; }
.container {background: #fff;}
footer, header, menu, nav, section {display: block; }```
@AryaanSheth

Can you update the code in the original posting to match this. It will be easier to read and new people coming to this question will have the full context.

The original post has been updated @AryaanSheth

Please fully explain your answer and don't just dump a chunk of code expecting that everyone will understand it
